# Having parakeets in one's house

Tags: sources-mekorot, home-house, superstition, birds

Someone told me it's *Mazel Rah* (bad luck) to have parakeets in one's house.

Is there any source for this?

Comment: I don't think many people abide by this stringency (except maybe *de facto*, as many people happen to not own birds).

Answer (score 2):

Seffer Chassidim #1038 quotes Koheles 6 11 that there are many things which increase hevel, and explains it to mean someone who raises birds for pleasure, adding what he spends on them he should rather give to the poor.

Mekor chessed there brings similar points, and sends to Tzavaas Rabi Tehuda Hachasid 53 and his own notes there. In that note he quotes the seffer Nagid Umitzvah in the name of Arizal not to raise pigeons or doves in one's house because his children will die or he won't have children. (As @Fred pointed out, this language is also found in the azharos nosafos of the Ztavaoth section)

Rabbi Margolios there also quotes other scary sources like Chupas Eliyahu at the end of Reishis Chachma, and Maharsha in Sota 48 d.h. zimra babayis.

Comment: Regarding what you mentioned in the name of the Arizal, [see here](https://sites.google.com/site/sagesofashkenaz/tzevos-r-yehuda-hechasid) #8 from the *azharos nosafos*: "לא יגדל אדם תורים ובני יונה בתוך ביתו (ע' סי' תתרל"ח). לפי שהבית אשר יגדלו בה או ימותו בניו או לא יהיה לו זרע."